# HTML Email Office 365 (OWA) Table Rendering Error

Tags: html, css, html-email, outlook-web-app

I am creating an email signature which is made up of a sliced image. Here is how the image should fit together:
[image]

Below is the code:

```
<table width="406" height="136" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" height="82">
      <img src="img/Rectangle_1.png" width="406" height="82" alt="" style="display: block;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" height="54">
      <img src="img/Rectangle_2.png" width="25" height="54" alt="" style="display: block;"></td>
    <td height="40">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/Rectangle_3.png" width="134" height="40" alt="" style="display: block; border:0; outline: none; text-decoration: none;"></a></td>
    <td height="40">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/Rectangle_4.png" width="125" height="40" alt="" style="display: block; border:0; outline: none; text-decoration: none;"></a></td>
    <td rowspan="2" height="54">
      <img src="img/Rectangle_5.png" width="122" height="54" alt="" style="display: block;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" height="14" style="line-height: 14px;">
      <img src="img/Rectangle_6.png" width="259" height="14" alt="" style="display: block;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This renders perfectly in nearly all mail clients apart from Office365 (in any browser). View screenshots for all clients/browsers https://www.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/viewresult/tUjH3Kk7JSzaD5D0F6X2agbPFHRkUvVfkGetyDv2hMgll. The below screenshot shows Office365 in IE11.

[image]

I can not seem to fix this whitespace issue nor the outline around the linked images. I have tried both the fixes listed here http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/two_fixes_for_image_spacing_in_outlook_web_app_owa but neither of them have worked. `align="left"` fixed it in Office365 in both Chrome and Firefox but it remained broken in other browsers moreover it broke the layout in many other clients. It was a similar story for the `div` fix. See screenshots for all clients/browsers with align left 'fix' here https://www.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/viewresult/SyapFGGm5JKUgTdZEs6L7oqlmHLOuQqMcFQGM307uA7LH

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue without causing issues for the other clients/browsers?

Many Thanks

Answer (score -1):

when using images you need to also use the align = rule to remove the spaces in owa

It is a huge pain

```
<img src="img/Rectangle_2.png" width="25" height="54" alt="" align="center" style="display: block;">
```

if it is just solid colors you should stick to background color for tables

Comment: You don't need to use align for OWA. I think he's using the solid color images as placeholders for an eventual collage of images.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to replicate your issue. To fix it, remove all the hard returns in your code; it looks like the signature html editor adds in multiple non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`) that causes the image alignment issues. Note how all the code appears on one line below; it will wrap as necessary in the html editor.

```
<table width="406" height="136" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;"> <tr> <td colspan="4" height="82"> <img src="img/Rectangle_1.png" width="406" height="82" alt="" style="display: block;"></td></tr><tr> <td rowspan="2" height="54"> <img src="img/Rectangle_2.png" width="25" height="54" alt="" style="display: block;"></td><td height="40"> <a href="#"><img src="img/Rectangle_3.png" width="134" height="40" alt="" style="display: block; border:0; outline: none; text-decoration: none;"></a></td><td height="40"> <a href="#"><img src="img/Rectangle_4.png" width="125" height="40" alt="" style="display: block; border:0; outline: none; text-decoration: none;"></a></td><td rowspan="2" height="54"> <img src="img/Rectangle_5.png" width="122" height="54" alt="" style="display: block;"></td></tr><tr> <td colspan="2" height="14" style="line-height: 14px;"> <img src="img/Rectangle_6.png" width="259" height="14" alt="" style="display: block;"></td></tr></table>
```

One other thing - the images that are hyperlinked (inside `<a>` tags) need a border attribute set to zero instead of setting it via inline CSS.

```
<a href=""><img src="" width="" alt="" border="0" style="display:block;"/>
```